# MSVC function demangling

Tags: c++, visual-c++, name-mangling

I have next functions:

```
namespace TEST {
    class TEST {
        int a;
        int b;
    };
}

namespace UNION_TEST {
    union UNION_TEST {
        int a;
        int b;
    };
}

union UNION_TEST_NEW {
    int a;
    int b;
};

namespace NAMESPACE_1 {
    namespace NAMESPACE_2 {
        union UNION_NAMESPACE_2 {
            int a, b;
        };
    }
}


void f1(UNION_TEST::UNION_TEST t, UNION_TEST::UNION_TEST t1) {
    return;
}

void f2(UNION_TEST::UNION_TEST t, TEST::TEST c, UNION_TEST::UNION_TEST t1) {
    return;
}

void f3(UNION_TEST_NEW u) {
    return;
}

void f4(NAMESPACE_1::NAMESPACE_2::UNION_NAMESPACE_2 u, TEST::TEST c, UNION_TEST::UNION_TEST t1) {
    return;
}
```

And correspond mangled symbols are:

```
0x000034e0  2  .text  ?f1@@YAXTUNION_TEST@1@0@Z
0x00003500  2  .text  ?f2@@YAXTUNION_TEST@1@VTEST@2@0@Z
0x00003520  2  .text  ?f3@@YAXTUNION_TEST_NEW@@@Z
0x00003530  2  .text  ?f4@@YAXTUNION_NAMESPACE_2@NAMESPACE_2@NAMESPACE_1@@VTEST@4@TUNION_TEST@5@@Z
```

Accroding to this http://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf (page 27) we have that union X -> TX@@, so why for the function f1, f2 there is no @@ at the end and how than distiguish when union with namespace is end and start next argument?

Thank U for attention and help.

Comment: Whatever problem you are trying to solve, staring at the mangled name is very unlikely to solve it.  A decent guide [is here](http://mearie.org/documents/mscmangle/).  Be specific about the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you observed, the claim that a union name `X` is transformed to `TX@@` is not a correct description of the name mangling used by your MSVC version. Note that "agner.org" is not associated with Microsoft, and doesn't provide official documentation.

As for your question how the different parts of a mangled name are separated, it appears that a single @ is sufficient.

Comment: yeap, but than I have next: TUNION_TEST@1@0@Z How to undetstand tha 0@ - is not namespace of UNION_TEST@1 ?

Comment: ?f4@@YAXTUNION_NAMESPACE_2@NAMESPACE_2@NAMESPACE_1@@VTEST@4@TUNION_TEST@5@@Z - and for this case, for example, the end of union with namesapces is @@, so this is possible to understand where is the end of namespaces...

Comment: @0 is a backreference to the first _token_. Don't assume name mangling encodes the type of a name, I see no indication of that. As for your second comment, I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: ?f5@@YAXTUNION_TEST@1NAMESPACE_1@@VTEST@3@T11@@Z - (NAMESPACE_1::UNION_TEST::UNION_TEST t, TEST::TEST c, UNION_TEST::UNION_TEST t1 . Why for this case after 1 there is no @?